# filter the_content() to render text before all images attached to the post

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

How can I filter the_content() to use this snippet after the text of the post and after that get all images attached to the post?

```
$attimages = get_attached_media('image', $post->ID);
foreach ($attimages as $image) {
    echo wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID).'<br>';
}
```

eg.

this is the content of my post

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same hook [the_content](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/).

```php
<?php

add_filter('the_content', 'filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop', 1);

function filter_the_content_in_the_main_loop($content)
{
    // Check if we're inside the main loop in a single Post.
    if (is_singular() && in_the_loop() && is_main_query()) {
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $attimages = get_attached_media('image', $post_id);
        foreach ($attimages as $image) {
            $content .= wp_get_attachment_url($image->ID) . '<br>';
        }
    }

    return $content;
}
```